# Select from table and associated

Tags: cakephp

I've have these tables:
 - Proyectos
 - Hitos
 - Tareas

*a **project** belongs to user and has many **hitos** and (optionally) **tareas**

*a **hito** belongs to **user** and **project** and has many **hitos** and (optionally) **tareas**

*a **tarea** belongs to **user**, **project** and **hito**

Now I want to retrieve those hitos which belong to user and those tareas which belong to the same user with this code:

```
$con1=array('OR'   =>  array(
            'Hito.usuario_id'=>$this->Session->read('Usuario_id'),
            'Tarea.usuario_id'  =>  $this->Session->read('Usuario_id'),
        ));

$this->loadModel('Hito');
$hitos = $this->Hito->find('all',array(
     'conditions' => $con1,
     'group'=>array('Hito.id'),
));
```

I only get the Hitos part... I have some related tareas that I need to be in $hitos

Does someone know how to get them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that with "Query"

```
$this->loadModel('Hito');
$hitos = $this->Hito->query(
    "select *
            from hitos as Hito
            left join tareas as Tarea on (Hito.id = Tarea.hito_id)
            left join usuarios as Usuario on (Hito.usuario_id = Usuario.id)
            where Hito.usuario_id =" . $this->Session->read('Usuario_id') . "
    OR Tarea.usuario_id=" . $this->Session->read('Usuario_id') . "
            group by Hito.id");
```

Change the SQL for whatever you need but dont forgot de "as Modelname" part for having your actual views working.

Comment: You don't need to do this with CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without seeing your Model code, but if the associations are setup correctly, CakePHP should retrieve all related model data for any given model. It will then be accessible like:

```
$oneUser = $this->read(null,$id);
debug($oneUser['Hito']); // array of all hitos for that user
debug($oneUser['Tarea']; // array of tareas for that user
debug($oneUser['User']); // the user data.
```